# Java 2D Arrays List throws an error when objects are not added with an orderly index format

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to understand why JVM throws an error when I try to add other Arrays lists into a 2D Array without indexing them by order.
Normally I don't get an error when I add the Arrays with an orderly Index sequence. But I am curious to understand why I get an error when I don't. I am new to Java

```java
 public class DoSomething {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> frisbeTeams = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> zen = new ArrayList<>();
        zen.add("iman");
        zen.add("dave");
        zen.add("jairo");
        zen.add("victor");
        zen.add("gene");
        zen.add("chor");

        ArrayList<String> szupa = new ArrayList<>();
        szupa.add("sam");
        szupa.add("mary");
        szupa.add("eman");
        szupa.add("louise");

        ArrayList<String> avocado = new ArrayList<>();
        avocado.add("ran");
        avocado.add("lana");
        avocado.add("winky");

        
    }



}
```

When I add the Arrays with an ordered Index format like this, It works

```java
frisbeTeams.add(0,avocado);
        frisbeTeams.add(1,zen);
        frisbeTeams.add(2,szupa);

        System.out.println(frisbeTeams);
```

But, When I randomly Index like this. I get an error

```java
 frisbeTeams.add(0,avocado);
        frisbeTeams.add(2,zen);
        frisbeTeams.add(1,szupa);
```

*error*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:756)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:481)
    at org.learn.DoSomething.main(DoSomething.java:29)
```

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc for the `add(int, E)` method?

Comment: No, but I am aware Java Arrays are immutable @tgdavies. 
I feel it is possible to add objects with disordered indexes if it fills the Array length. Or maybe I am doing it the wrong way. Thanks

Comment: Read the Javadoc, and then you'll know what the method does, and why you see the error you do.

Comment: Since the index you are putting object into is going out of size it is throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException. If you want to avoid it then make sure the index used is always less than the size of the array.

Comment: @JavaSamurai, but if the arraylist is already full and if we try to insert new element, the size of arraylist automatically grows by 10 if I am right... So that shouldn't be the case

Comment: Yes but that is the case when you are using add without defining index. The point of inserting at specific index is to have an object already. add with index would always increase you list but prerequisite to have an object already at that index because what if you want to add object at position 12 in array of size 10?

Comment: @JavaSamurai but the size of the array is 0-2, if add objects less than that I will get an error

Comment: When you don't understand the behaviour of a method, the *first* thing to do is to read the friendly manual. If you still don't understand, by all means ask a question here.

Comment: I have added objects from 0-2 but not in an ordered format. When added orderly, everything works well. But I want to understand why I get an error when the index of the objects are not arranged in an ordered format.

Comment: If you go through the definition of add function you are concerned with [here](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/java.util.ArrayList/rangeCheckForAdd), you can see that size of arraylist for this function is growing by 1 each time you call the funtion.